# Different regression output using dynlm and lm

Tags: r, time-series, lm

I ran a regression first using `lm` and then using `dynlm`(from the package `dynlm`). Here is what I did using `lm`:

```
Euribor3t <- ts(diff(Euribor3))
OIS3t <- ts(diff(Ois3))
x <- ts(diff(Eurepo3-Ois3))
Vstoxxt <- ts(diff(Vstoxx))
CDSt <- ts(diff(CDS))
omo2 <- ts(diff(log(Open.Market.Operations)))
l1 <- (lag(Euribor3t, k=-1))
axx <- ts.intersect(Euribor3t, OIS3t, x, Vstoxxt, CDSt, omo2, l1)
reg1 <- lm(Euribor3t~OIS3t+CDSt+x+Vstoxxt+omo2+l1, data=axx)
summary(reg1)
```

and for `dynlm`:

```
zooX = zoo(test[, -1])
lmx <- dynlm(d(Euribor3)~d(Ois3)+d(CDS)+d(Eurepo3-Ois3)+d(Vstoxx)+d(log(Open.Market.Operations))+d(L(Euribor3, 1)), data=zooX)
summary(lmx)
```

These two approaches give me exact the same output. However if I add a subset to both regressions from 1 to 24 (all else equal):

```
Euribor3t <- ts(diff(Euribor3))
OIS3t <- ts(diff(Ois3))
x <- ts(diff(Eurepo3-Ois3))
Vstoxxt <- ts(diff(Vstoxx))
CDSt <- ts(diff(CDS))
omo2 <- ts(diff(log(Open.Market.Operations)))
l1 <- (lag(Euribor3t, k=-1))
axx <- ts.intersect(Euribor3t, OIS3t, x, Vstoxxt, CDSt, omo2, l1)
reg1 <- lm(Euribor3t~OIS3t+CDSt+x+Vstoxxt+omo2+l1, data=axx, subset=1:24)
summary(reg1)

zooX = zoo(test[, -1])
lmx <- dynlm(d(Euribor3)~d(Ois3)+d(CDS)+d(Eurepo3-Ois3)+d(Vstoxx)+d(log(Open.Market.Operations))+d(L(Euribor3, 1)), data=zooX[1:24])
summary(lmx)
```

The two outputs differ from each other. What might be the problem causing the deviation in my regression outputs?

Here is the data sample I experimented with:

```
    Date    Euribor3    Ois3    Eurepo3 Vstoxx  CDS Open.Market.Operations
1   03.01.2005  2.154   2.089   2.09    14.47   17.938  344999
2   04.01.2005  2.151   2.084   2.09    14.51   17.886  344999
3   05.01.2005  2.151   2.087   2.08    14.42   17.950  333998
4   06.01.2005  2.150   2.085   2.08    13.80   17.950  333998
5   07.01.2005  2.146   2.086   2.08    13.57   17.913  333998
6   10.01.2005  2.146   2.087   2.08    12.92   17.958  333998
7   11.01.2005  2.146   2.089   2.08    13.68   17.962  333998
8   12.01.2005  2.145   2.085   2.08    14.05   17.886  339999
9   13.01.2005  2.144   2.084   2.08    13.64   17.568  339999
10  14.01.2005  2.144   2.085   2.08    13.57   17.471  339999
11  17.01.2005  2.143   2.085   2.08    13.20   17.365  339999
12  18.01.2005  2.144   2.085   2.08    13.17   17.214  347999
13  19.01.2005  2.143   2.086   2.08    13.63   17.143  354499
14  20.01.2005  2.144   2.087   2.08    14.17   17.125  354499
15  21.01.2005  2.143   2.087   2.08    13.96   17.193  354499
16  24.01.2005  2.143   2.086   2.08    14.11   17.283  354499
17  25.01.2005  2.144   2.086   2.08    13.63   17.083  354499
18  26.01.2005  2.143   2.086   2.08    13.32   17.348  347999
19  27.01.2005  2.144   2.085   2.08    12.46   17.295  352998
20  28.01.2005  2.144   2.084   2.08    12.81   17.219  352998
21  31.01.2005  2.142   2.084   2.08    12.72   17.143  352998
22  01.02.2005  2.142   2.083   2.08    12.36   17.125  352998
23  02.02.2005  2.141   2.083   2.08    12.25   17.000  357499
24  03.02.2005  2.144   2.088   2.08    12.38   16.808  357499
25  04.02.2005  2.142   2.084   2.08    11.60   16.817  357499
26  07.02.2005  2.142   2.084   2.08    11.99   16.798  359999
27  08.02.2005  2.141   2.083   2.08    11.92   16.804  355500
28  09.02.2005  2.142   2.080   2.08    12.19   16.589  355500
29  10.02.2005  2.140   2.080   2.08    12.04   16.500  355500
30  11.02.2005  2.140   2.078   2.08    11.99   16.429  355500
31  14.02.2005  2.139   2.078   2.08    12.52   16.042  355500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowing `dynlm` to use the same amount of data as in `lm`. The latter model contains two fewer observations.

```
dim(model.frame(reg1))
# [1] 24  7
dim(model.frame(lmx))
# [1] 22  7
```

The reason is that with`lm` you are transforming the variables (differencing) with the entire data set (31 observations), while in `dynlm` you are passing only 24 observations and, hence, `dynlm` will do the differencing with 24 observations. Due to the observations that are lost after differencing, the resulting number of rows is not the same in both cases.

In `dylm` you should use `data=zooX[1:26]`. In this way the same subset is used and the same result is obtained:

```
reg1 <- lm(Euribor3t~OIS3t+CDSt+x+Vstoxxt+omo2+l1, data=axx, subset=1:24)
lmx <- dynlm(d(Euribor3)~d(Ois3)+d(CDS)+d(Eurepo3-Ois3)+d(Vstoxx)+
  d(log(Open.Market.Operations))+d(L(Euribor3, 1)), data=zooX[1:26])
all.equal(as.vector(fitted(reg1)), as.vector(fitted(lmx)))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(coef(reg1), coef(lmx), check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I have one last question regarding the use of subsets though. Assuming I want to divide my data frame into several subsets (for example: 1:10, 11:20 and 21:31) and then run a regression for each subset. Is it correct that in this case the `lm` approach is more appropriate since I loose fewer observation than with the `dynlm` approach? Using `dynlm` for the cases 1:10 and 11:20 I could correct the subsets as you mentioned in your answer, but for the last subset (21:31) this doesn't work (because I only have 31 observations. So I assume the `lm` approach is more suitable. Is this correct? Thanks

Comment: I didn't check it but if I am correct, using the following indices in `lm` 
1:10, 11:20, 21:31 and 1:12, 11:22, 21:31 in `dynlm` will yield the same results. There is no need to adjust the last subsample 21:31 because 
in either case there are no more observations to be gained on the right side (contrary to what happens when a susample is the take in the middle of the series).